# Run notepad.exe from a html-button using Awesomium

Tags: c#, wpf, awesomium

I've been looking for an example on how to open a process like notepad.exe from a html-element using WPF and Awesomium 1.7.5. The idea is that clicking a html element triggers a C# method using javascript as far as I understand the Awesomium API. However, all examples I can find refer to an earlier version that now uses obsolete functions...

Can anyone please provide me with an example on how to execute C#-code when openNotepad() is triggered?

HTML:

```
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>  
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="app.openNotepad()">This button will open Notepad</button>
</body>
</html>
```

C#:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        webControl.Source = new Uri("index.html");
    }

    private void webControl_DocumentReady(object sender, DocumentReadyEventArgs e)
    {
        BindMethods(webControl);
    }

    private void BindMethods(IWebView _webView)
    {
        JSValue result = webControl.CreateGlobalJavascriptObject("app");
        if (result.IsObject)
        {
            JSObject appObject = result;
            appObject.Bind("openNotepad", openNotepad);
        }
    }

    private JSValue openNotepad(object obj, JavascriptMethodEventArgs jsMethodArgs)
    {
        Process.Start("notepad.exe");
        return null;
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:awe="http://schemas.awesomium.com/winfx" x:Class="Omega.MainWindow"
        Title="Omega" Height="350" Width="525" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" WindowState="Maximized" ResizeMode="NoResize" Topmost="True" WindowStyle="None">
    <Grid>

        <awe:WebControl x:Name="webControl" DocumentReady="webControl_DocumentReady" />

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: like this? http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/113678/How-to-execute-a-Local-File-using-HTML-Application

Comment: No. Awesomium is based on webkit and only IE supports ActiveXObject. I've updated my main post with the current C# code behind.

Comment: Your C# code looks good, and it should work as intended. What problems have you faced, what goes wrong? Are you getting exception?

Comment: Yes:
'Awesomium.Core.JavascriptMethodEventHandler' is obsolete: 'This delegate is deprecated. Please use JavascriptMethodDelegate that allows you to return a result directly from the method.'

'Awesomium.Core.JSObject.Bind(string, bool, Awesomium.Core.JavascriptMethodEventHandler)' is obsolete: 'This method is deprecated. Please use any of the new overloads.'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Awesomium documentation to [Bind](http://docs.awesomium.net/html/M_Awesomium_Core_JSObject_Bind_2.htm) and [JavascriptMethodHandler](http://docs.awesomium.net/html/T_Awesomium_Core_JavascriptMethodHandler.htm), methods of handling Javascript events has changed in version 1.7.5.

[JavascriptMethodEventHandler](http://docs.awesomium.net/html/T_Awesomium_Core_JavascriptMethodEventHandler.htm) now obsolete, and new Bind overload should be used.

Now your code could look like

```
private void BindMethods(IWebView _webView)
{
    JSValue result = webControl.CreateGlobalJavascriptObject("app");
    if (result.IsObject)
    {
        JSObject appObject = result;
        appObject.Bind("openNotepad", openNotepad);
    }
}

private JSValue openNotepad(object obj, JavascriptMethodEventArgs jsMethodArgs)
{
    Process.Start("notepad.exe");
    return null;
}
```

Note, there is example of using new overload at the end of [Bind](http://docs.awesomium.net/html/M_Awesomium_Core_JSObject_Bind_2.htm) documentation page.

Also note that javascript method in your sample actually not calling `app.openNotepad()` method, but `alert("Run Notepad");`

Comment: Thanks for your last sentence! I see that I misunderstood how "CreateGlobalJavascriptObject" works! I've now updated my top post so it's a working solution. Hopefully this will help others. :)

Answer (score 0):

WshShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");

WshShell.Run("c:/windows/system32/notepad.exe", 1, false);

Comment: OP's question is about `Awesomium`. It is based on `WebKit` and does not support `ActiveXObject`